# FFmpeg стрим UDP через RTSP и RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

В данный момент имеется Raspberry Pi с на нем собранным FFmpeg.
Могу запускать UDP стримы и смотреть их через VLC Player.

```
raspivid -n -t 0 -fps 25 -b 500000 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts udp://@239.239.2.1:1234
```

Пытаюсь добиться следующего - RTSP стрим используя входной файл как UDP стрим.

```
ffmpeg  -i udp://239.239.2.1:1234 -vcodec copy -an -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.0.167:5545/live
```

Аналогично этому стрим RTMP на определеную машину, к примеру на OS X VLC Player:

```
ffmpeg  -i udp://239.239.2.1:1234 -vcodec copy -an -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtmp rtmp://192.168.0.167:1935/live
```

К сожалению, что первый, что второй вариант не работает.

Comment: Какая цель у вашего мероприятия? В браузер кино вывести?

Comment: @gbg нет, не в браузер.

Comment: так, и что мы конструируем в итоге? Вся эта штуковина из транспортов и кодеков - очень шаткая. Скажите, какая цель-то в итоге?

Comment: @gbg запись и стримы с помощью raspberry и его модуля камеры, raspivid

Comment: @gbg стрим можно только получить через VLC, другого мне не надо, а запись будет осуществляться тем-же ffmpeg и она уже работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И не будут работать. Для таких потоков нужен сервер вещания - либо `ffserver`, либо `nginx` с плагином `nginx-rtmp`

[Примерный конфиг для ffserver](https://www.ffmpeg.org/sample.html)

```
##################################################################
# RTSP examples
#
# You can access this stream with the RTSP URL:
#   rtsp://localhost:5454/test1-rtsp.mpg
#
# A non-standard RTSP redirector is also created. Its URL is:
#   http://localhost:8090/test1-rtsp.rtsp

#<Stream test1-rtsp.mpg>
#Format rtp
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test1.mpg"
#</Stream>


# Transcode an incoming live feed to another live feed,
# using libx264 and video presets

#<Stream live.h264>
#Format rtp
#Feed feed1.ffm
#VideoCodec libx264
#VideoFrameRate 24
#VideoBitRate 100
#VideoSize 480x272
#AVPresetVideo default
#AVPresetVideo baseline
#AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
#
#AudioCodec libfaac
#AudioBitRate 32
#AudioChannels 2
#AudioSampleRate 22050
#AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
#</Stream>


ffmpeg должен формировать файл ffm, который в дальнейшем ffserver будет транслировать.
```

Comment: тогда команды запуска rtmp/rtsp стрима тоже не правильны?

Comment: Они правильны наполовину. Левую. В правой нужно формировать файл вещания в формате ffm.

Кроме того, могут быть проблемы с кодеками - надо кодировать "дружелюбно к потоку", чтобы юзер не ждал ключевого кадра по полгода.

Comment: Можно немного больше информации? Какой кодек более дружелюбен и как правильно написать правую сторону?

Comment: Про дружелюбность: http://htrd.su/wiki/zhurnal/2014/09/24/x264_low_latency, а к серверам добавлю crtmpserver (он же crtmpd)

Comment: попробовал с ffmpeg и c crtmpserver, никакой способ не получается привести к работоспособности

Comment: @Insider я на аналогичный проект три недели извел и половину хабры перекопал. Но все заработало, благодаря методу научного тыка.

Comment: @gbg пытаюсь запустить хотя бы rtsp при помощи https://github.com/revmischa/rtsp-server однако к сожалению показывает  ошибку http://pastebin.com/5RdViG0u